# How to read epub files on rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, epub

What i would like to do is upload epub files in my app. Then I could enter a word and it will display all the sentences where this word appear. I try running this gem : https://github.com/KitaitiMakoto/epub-search

But i can't figure out how to use it on a rails application. I manage to get the results in the terminal but when i try to run the method in a controller and display it in a view, i get this error message :

```
Groonga::InvalidArgument in Home#index

Showing /home/louvivien/vivien/Camus/app/views/home/index.html.erb where line #7 raised:

invalid argument: [table][create] db not initialized: #<Groonga::Hash id: <2147483651>, name: (anonymous), path: (temporary), domain: (256), range: (nil), flags: <WITH_SUBREC>, size: <4>, encoding: <:utf8>, default_tokenizer: (nil), token_filters: [], normalizer: (nil)>
db.c:1078: grn_table_create_with_max_n_subrecs()
```

In the terminal, i see the results.

Do you know what I can to fix this error ?

This is my controller :

```
def index()
    color=$stdout.tty?
     highlight = [true, 'always'].include? color
    highlight = $stdout.tty? if color == 'auto'
    @db = EPUB::Search::Database.new('./lib/epub-search/db')
    @word = "condition"

    @result = @db.search @word do |result|
      EPUB::Search::Formatter::CLI.new(result, @word, highlight).format
                        end      
             end
```

Comment: I can't answer your question, but this epub-search gem looks do not anymore be maintained. However use [another thing](https://gitlab.com/KitaitiMakoto/epub-parser)?

Comment: thanks, I found a better solution with this one https://gitlab.com/KitaitiMakoto/epub-parser